# Resetting a new thread repetitively

Tags: java, multithreading, reset

In my program, there is a button, "Display", and another button, "Reset".
The user enters the number of prime numbers they want in the text field and then clicks the "Display" button. Then, the first x prime numbers will appear in the text area.

In the code, I have:
Declarations:

```
Thread go;
Thread newThread;
JLabel howManyLabel;
JTextField howMany;
JButton display;
JButton reset;
JTextArea primes;
```

Action Event:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();

    if (source == display) {
        display.setEnabled(false);
        if (go == null) {
            go = new Thread(this);
            go.start();
        } else {
            newThread = new Thread(this);
            newThread.start();
        }
    } else if (source == reset) {
        display.setEnabled(true);
        howMany.setText(" ");
        primes.setText(" ");
    }
}
```

Run method:

```
public void run() {
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(howMany.getText());
    int numPrimes = 0;
    int candidate = 2;  // candidate = the number that MIGHT be prime

    primes.append("First " + quantity + " primes:");
    while(numPrimes < quantity) {
        if (isPrime(candidate)) {
            primes.append(candidate + ", ");
            numPrimes++;
        }
        candidate++;
    }
}
```

The run() method is in the same class, and simply calculates the first x amount of prime numbers.

I am trying to create a new thread every time the "Reset" button is called. The thread runs the first time, but then does not run again after I click "Reset". Can the run() method only work once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the run method will run each time you start the thread.  Maybe the code in `run()` needs to be reinitialized?

Comment: What does the code in `run()` do?

Comment: Please add the member variable declarations for `display, go, newThread, howMany, primes` and the body of `run` so we can understand what's going on...

Comment: And please name your thread variables more meaningful than `go` and `newThread`!

Comment: I assume you don't actually mean that you want to create a new Thread every time the "Reset" button is hit?  It looks like you just want to reset your UI.  You should rephrase your question to convey your true intention.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the requests. I dont think its a problem with my run method though because it works the first time. I just dont know how to reset my THread

Comment: @Gray  what do you mean by reinitialized? How do I do that?

Comment: I'm just saying that the only way the `run()` method might not seem to run is if you have code that has a problem being called again.  In looking at your `run()` do you need to reinitialize something?

Comment: @Gray All the reinitialization is done the Reset button is clicked. The run method just has to do the same thing that it did the first time the Thread started

Comment: @JeffGohlke I have rephrased my question. How would I reset a thread?

Comment: @vmck You can't reset a `Thread`.  A `Thread` runs once and only once.  You have to create a new `Thread`, exactly as you're doing.

Comment: @JeffGohlke do you know why my above code attempting to create a new thread isn't working?

Comment: @vmck Nope.  Based on what you've posted, a new Thread should be running whenever you click the `display` button.  Your problem must be elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `run()` method is just like any other method and can be invoked any number of times. The method that cannot be invoked multiple times is `start()`(according to [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)).

Your explanation does not seem to fit with the code you gave. You say you want to spawn a new thread when a user clicks reset, yet you only construct or start threads if the source is Display. Did you mean, rather, that you want to cancel the last thread and enable controls for the user to start again? In that case you should use a `Future`, not a generic thread.

Another thing is that UI components are generally not thread-safe. Swing explicitly warns against it on every components JavaDoc. What you may be seeing is just components not updating their visible state when they are changed from a different thread. Have you tried using a debugger to see if a thread is actually not getting spawned, or it is being spawned, but not having the result you want?

Comment: how would I use a Future?

Comment: You would create and run one of the implementing classes. 
If using Swing, you would create a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) in which you can implement `doInBackground()` which would be the main workload. Every time it found a new prime it would use `publish` to give it to EDT. It would then invoke `process` on the published bits in the EDT (the GUI thread), updating your text area with the new number. When it is finished it would invoke `done` on the EDT again, finishing the thread. It also has a cancel method to stop.

Comment: Other options include using a `ScheduledExecutorService`, it depends really on what frameworks and libraries you are using. 
The main question still stands - what did the debugger tell you? Is there a problem in whether the Thread spawns or in what it does?

Comment: the debugger says:Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 7"
 
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)

 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)

 at PrimeFinder.run(PrimeFinder.java:80)

 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: Please post stack traces as code, otherwise the formatting is awful. I notice however that you have a space before the 7, which breaks the parser. I imagine this was the problem you faced earlier. 
What I would do is set the test fields to "" instead of " " (empty string, not space), and put the `parseInt()` in a try-catch block. That way you have indication whether the thread is not starting due to something weird, or it just doesn't recognize the number